# Proving That $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$, where $f(x) = x + 10$, Is Surjective

Tags: functions, proof-verification

I am trying to prove that $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$, where $f(x) = x + 10$, is surjective. I have included my reasoning and would appreciate it if people could check whether it is correct.

**My Proof**

Let $b \in \mathbb{Z}$.

We want to show that, for any $b \in \mathbb{Z}$, there exists some $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $b = f(x) = x + 10$.

$\therefore x = b - 10$ We constructed an integer $x$.

$\therefore f(x) = f(b - 10)$

$= (b - 10) + 10$ (By the hypothesis.)

$= b$

$= x + 10 \ \ \ Q.E.D. \ \ \ $ We have now demonstrated that $b = f(x) = x + 10$.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to review my proof and the reasoning I have included in it.

Comment: Yep:  if $b$ is an integer, so is $b-10$.

Comment: It's fine. A little wordy, but that's OK for a beginner. You shouldn't use "therefore $x$ " the first time, you should say "Let $x$ ...

Comment: Also, you could conclude that $f(x) = f(b-10)= \cdots = b$ and be done instead of the extra lines that came after.

Comment: @EthanBolker Ok, I will change it to "Let $x$ ...". Thanks.

Comment: @Randall So exclude the $= x + 10$ part at the end?

Comment: @ThePointer  yes, it is not needed and redundant.

Comment: @Randall Ok, will do. Thank you all for the review.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof  is fine.

Here with minute differences in style:

Need to show that $f$ is surjective.

Let $b \in {Z}.$

Need to find an $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that

$f(a)=b$.

Choose $a= b-10 $, then

$f(a)=(b-10)+10 = b.$

Done.